# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper

Tags: java, android, toast

I get the following error:

```
08-27 17:49:17.995: E/AndroidRuntime(10085): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-27 17:49:17.995: E/AndroidRuntime(10085):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
08-27 17:49:17.995: E/AndroidRuntime(10085):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:361)
08-27 17:49:17.995: E/AndroidRuntime(10085):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:97)
08-27 17:49:17.995: E/AndroidRuntime(10085):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:254)
```

when running the first line of:

```
public static void alertUser(String str) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mInstance.getApplicationContext(), str,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

}
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: seems you are updating ui from a thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public static void alertUser(String str) {

runOnUiThread(setErrorMessage); 

}


private Runnable setErrorMessage = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mInstance.getApplicationContext(), str,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
    }
};
```

Comment: but on this answer, they have suggested something else : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467470/threading-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepar